# LightSwitch application problem

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have opened my first light switch application.

When I click properties on the solution and go to the Application Type , i don't have the options where i choose 2-tier or 3-tier. Instead , i have -

"Choose the client and server topology for your application:" label , and i have the next options :

Desktop , Web.

In the tutorial i saw that i need to choose 2-tier....

Also , i  don't have an checkboxes Like : Allow export to Excel....

I have installed vs2010 sp1 , and LigjtSwitch Beta2

what could be the problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this yet with beta 2, but I think you would find Beth's [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/03/23/deployment-guide-how-to-configure-a-web-server-to-host-lightswitch-applications.aspx) very helpful (scroll down to Direct Publishing a LightSwitch Application if you don't need to configure a server). Also, the official documentation on doing this is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg481778.aspx).